# Blazor WebAssembly Environment Variables

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I'm currently working on a .NET Standard 2.1 Blazor WebAssembly application.
I try to include or exclude Stylesheets according to an environment variable.

In .NET Core there are usually Environment Tag Helpers like in the following example:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" />
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.min.css" type="text/css" />
</environment>
```

This works perfectly fine in a Blazor Server application, but doesn't in Blazor WASm, as this is client-side code.

Thus I try to find a good solution to **include/exclude Style sheets according to the Environment variable** in Blazor WebAssembly.

My current approach is to call a JavaScript helper method from my Blazor WASm Program.cs file with JSInterop and remove the Stylesheets according to the environment variable:

```
await jsInterop.InvokeVoidAsync("helpers.setup", "Development");
```

My JavaScript on the client looks like this:

```
window.helpers = {
    setup: (environment) => {

        if (environment === "Development") {
            // remove production styles
        }

        if (environment !== "Development") {
            // remove development styles
        }
    }
};
```

The problem with this solution is, I want to put my styles into my header file and group them into a `<section>` element or something similar - which doesn't work in valid HTML5.

How do you handle your Development/Production environment in Blazor WebAssembly?

How can you exclude or include specific CSS files according to the set environment variable in the project settings (launchsettings.json)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Disclaimer:**

***This is just something I tried that seems to work. I could not find any documentation supporting doing it this way, nor anything saying not to do it this way.*** if there is any official documentation please let me know.

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) state:

> When running an app locally, the environment defaults to Development.
> When the app is published, the environment defaults to Production.

Further down it does mention how to set the environment via the web.config that gets generated when publishing the file to IIS.
There are also references to [Use multiple environments in ASP.NET Core.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and [Host and deploy ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-a-custom-webconfig)

However this is what I did.

Looking at the `Program.cs` file that was generated by the *new web assembly project template*, the `builder` is created by `WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);` This must mean that all the *default* services must already be registered in the services container.

This would include the `IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment` configuration service.

The next line down  `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");` adds the App `<app></app>` root ***component*** that is used in the *`index.html`* file.

So, *Why not try to create a Head `<head></head>` ***component*** and see what happens.*

I created a Head razor component and named it `Head.razor` containing all the *html* that would usually live between the `<head></head>` tags.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting
@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment hostEnv

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<base href="/" />
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />

@*Check the environment value*@
@if (hostEnv.IsDevelopment())
{
    <title>BlazorWasmApp - In Debug</title>
    <link href="css/debug.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
else
{
    <title>BlazorWasmApp - Not Debug</title>
    <link href="css/live.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}

@code {}
```

Because it is a ***component*** you can inject the `IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment` and check the `.IsDevelopment()`,`.IsProduction()` etc.. extension method values.

I left the original `<head>` tag as is in the `index.html` file as the content of the `<head>...gets overwritten...</head>` seems to be completely overwritten.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>BlazorWasmApp</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>    
...
...
```

Also leaving the `<head>`tag with the reference to the `cs/app.css` file does not change the way it looks when the app is *Loading....*

I registered the `Head` class to the `builder.RootComponents` collection in the `Program` class.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);            
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

    //Add the Head to root components
    builder.RootComponents.Add<Head>("head");            
            
    builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });           
    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

I added 2 css files to the *`wwwroot/css`* folder *`debug.css`* and *`live.css`* each containing a simple `body { background-color:*red or blue* }` style.

In the `launchSettings.json` file, in the profiles section, set the `IIS Express : environmentVariables : ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to "*Development*" and under the `[YourAppName] : environmentVariables : ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to "*Production*".

```
"profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    },
    "BlazorWasmApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Production"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}"
    }
  }
```

When launching the app with the *IIS Express* profile (Development) the background is **red** and when launching the app with *[YourAppName]* profile (Production) the background is **blue**.

When looking at the `<head></head>` tags using the developer tools the content of the head tag contains the css references according to the environment.

IIS Express:

[image: Red Dev]

BlazorWasmApp (my app profile):

[image: Blue Prod]

Comment: thanks for your idea. This approach works very well in this Blazor WASm release. The only issue I found is, that the <head> component is rendered after the DOM of the index.html was setup. That means, I would still need a separate CSS for the Loading section <app>Loading...</app> or the blazor-error-ui div... Do you perhaps have another idea on how to solve this?

Comment: The <head> content is over written, so you could leave the original head tag as is, with the reference to app.css stylesheet. I'll update the answer to include this.

Comment: and what in case you host your application with static files on azure storage account / behind CDN, then nothing on server side is set... :/ it should detect during runtime using URL somehow if i see it correctly..

Comment: Where would you put <script> tags, such as for google analytics? Gives an error saying that script tags cannot be used in components. But I can't leave it back in the original head tag as that will be overwritten?

Comment: @user1227445 a possible solution could be to add the `@((MarkupString)@"<script src=""dev.url""></script>")` in the block as required. I have not worked with Blazor for quite some time now, so it's a best guess.

Comment: @user1227445, I have also not done any work with google analytics, so if this works please let me know and I can add it to the answer

Comment: Very promising, but failed for me on refresh.