# Blazor WebAssembly load different scripts for specific Environment

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

I'm currently working on a .NET Standard 2.1 Blazor WebAssembly application. I try to **include or exclude JavaScript files in my index.html** according to an environment variable.

The Blazor WebAssembly App is NOT Asp.NET Core hosted.

[image]

In .NET Core there are usually Environment Tag Helpers like in the following example:

```
<environment include="Development">
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/helpers.js"></script>
</environment>

<environment exclude="Development">
    <script src="js/site.min.js"></script>
</environment>
```

As already discussed in this question [Blazor WebAssembly Environment Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63052399/blazor-webassembly-environment-variables), the Environment Tag Helpers are server side code and thus don't work in Blazor WASm.

Now I try to find a good solution to include/exclude JavaScript files according to the Environment variable in Blazor WebAssembly.

The first idea was, similar like for CSS, to create a component called `<Scripts>` to load the different script files on the index.html like this:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting
@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment hostEnv
   
@*Check the environment value*@
@if (hostEnv.IsDevelopment())
{
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/helpers.js"></script>
}
else
{
    <script src="js/site.min.js"></script>
}

@code {}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work, because the `<script>` Element is not allowed to be used in a Blazor component (.razor file).

The following error occurs: **The script element allows authors to include dynamic script and data blocks in their documents. The element does not represent content for the user. ... Script tags should not be placed inside components because they cannot be updated dynamically. To fix this, move the script tag to the 'index.html' file or another static location. ... https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=872131**

How do you load different scripts according to the Environment Variable i.e. Development, Production or Staging in Blazor Webassembly?

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply copy your index.html code in a .cshtml (named BlazorApp.cshtml in the following sample) in your server project and fallback to this page.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
...
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        ...
        endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/BlazorApp");
    }
}
```

And update the code with `<environment>` tags for your conveniance.

Comment: thanks, would you mind to provide some more information on how to "fallback" to a .cshtml file - the index.html is located in the wwwroot folder in Blazor WebAssembly (.Net Standard 2.1)?

Comment: Thank you agua from mars, this works very well in a "ASP.NET Core hosted" application with a server and client project. In my case I can only use a Client project unfortunately. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: You are going to deploy in a static page ?

Comment: Thanks - the idea is to have a Blazor Client fronted that communicates with backend REST Apis (CRUD)... I guess a 'static page' should be enough, what do you think?

Comment: I'd like to use Blazor instead of Vue.js or Angular or ...

Comment: It depends how and where you plan to deploy, if it's with kestrel or IIS or if you gonna have an API in dotnet core then prefer to use a blazor wasm hosted solution

Comment: In my application landscape I cannot use SignalR due to "governance restrictions" - that's the main problem... Do you know, is ASP.NET core hosted Blazor dependent on SignalR?

Comment: You don't need signalR it's only required for Blazor server. Blazor WASM doesn't depend on SignalR

Comment: Your solution works very well, though I consider the extra "Server" project as an overhead, especially if the business logic is in the API layer. Thus I wrote a small JavaScript to load the scripts on Startup, according to the environment variable (passed as a param via jsInterop). It's not a very appealing solution, but I'm sure Microsoft will provide a better way sooner or later.

Comment: @azzurro123 May be yes, may be no :) May be there is another solution to solve you issue, I think about extract configuration you need per environment and pass the good configuration stored in the *appsettings.{Env}.json* to the a single script instead.

Comment: Let's see - the appsettings file is another good idea, thanks!

Comment: @aguafrommars I tried your solution but it seems to break navigation when refreshing the page as per this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64412156/blazor-webassembly-with-index-file-configuration-logic-causing-ambiguousmatchexc). I assume this is some kind of conflict between client side and server side navigation. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @OjM open a new question for this issue

Comment: @aguafrommars I did already as per link in previous comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add Tailwind CDN script tag just during development. I ended up using the solution below:

index.html

```html
    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script>
        // If localhost, add tailwind CDN (or any other script that you want)
        if (window.location.hostname == 'localhost') {
                var customScript = document.createElement('script');
                customScript.setAttribute('src', 'https://cdn.tailwindcss.com');
                document.head.appendChild(customScript);
        }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061239/1158845) (same question as you linked above) and that seems to work.

Basically the workaround is to use this in a new component called `Head.razor` as per the solution:

```
@inject IWebAssemblyHostEnvironment hostEnv

@if (hostEnv.IsDevelopment())
{
    <title>BlazorWasmApp - In Debug</title>
    <link href="css/debug.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
else
{
    <title>BlazorWasmApp - Not Debug</title>
    <link href="css/live.css" rel="stylesheet" />
}
```

New `Head.razor` component:

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);            
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

    //Add the Head to root components
    builder.RootComponents.Add<Head>("head");            
            
    builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });           
    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't really work with the <script> element, it is not allowed to be used in a component. It's possible to surpass the error, but I don't feel like this is the right way to do it...

Comment: You can not use script element in the component, its not allowed, see this: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16218

Comment: yes, but the questions remains, how to load <script> (javascript) according to an environment variable set in launchSettings.json in Blazor Wasm...

Comment: Sorry my bad, I understand your question now, because the Head is a razor page and it doesn't allow script tags. I was overlooking your question. I will get back if I find anything.