# Blazor wasm: adding custom environment does not work

Tags: asp.net-core, environment-variables, blazor-webassembly

**EDIT:** I've rewritten the post to give more info and added a link to github sample project.

I'm trying to support an extra environment for testing a hosted wasm application. The solution has 2 projects and I've named the new environment `Express`. Btw, [here's](https://github.com/luisabreu/BlazorHostedDemo) a demo project that reproduces the problem I'm facing.

After creating a new project based on the Blazor wasm hosted template, I've started by adding 2 new html pages to the blazor wwwroot's folder (there are 3 HTML files, each for a different environment):

[image: 3 html fiels for each environment]

In this simple demo, the only difference between the files consists in the way blazor is started. For instance, here's the code used for loading blazor in the `index.express.html` file:

```
<script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js" autostart="false"></script>
<script>
    Blazor.start({
        environment: "Express"
    });
</script>
```

In the real app, there are other differences (ex.: `<base>` element), but for now, this is more than enough for showcasing the problem.

On the server side, I've added a new `appsettings` file:

[image: Appsettings files on the server project]

I've also updated the `lauchSettings.json` server file so that it sets the `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` variable to `Express`:

```
  "BlazorHostedDemo.Server": {
    "commandName": "Project",
    "dotnetRunMessages": true,
    "launchBrowser": true,
    "inspectUri": "{wsProtocol}://{url.hostname}:{url.port}/_framework/debug/ws-proxy?browser={browserInspectUri}",
    "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7261;http://localhost:5261",
    "environmentVariables": {
      "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Express" 
    }
  },
```

I'm under the impression that this should be enough for making Kestrel use the Express environment.

I've also updated the default filename used for loading the blazor app so that it depends on the profile:

```
var filename = app.Environment.IsDevelopment()
                   ? "index.development.html"
                   : app.Environment.IsEnvironment("Express")
                       ? "index.express.html"
                       : "index.html";

app.MapFallbackToFile(filename);
```

After doing theses changes, I expected Kestrel to use the `Express` environment and  the `index.express.html` file to be loaded, but that isn't happening. As you can see, Kestrel is using the "correct" environment:

[image: Express environment being used by Kestrell]

However, kestrel is returning 404 for the default page (`index.express.html` file):

[image: Kestrel/ASP.NET Core does not return the fallback HTML file]

Btw, this is not a filename issue or missing file problem. For instance, if I use the default index.html for the express environment, I still get the same result:

```
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

I've also noticed that if I set the environment to `Development` (by changing the `launchSettings.json` file) I can serve any of the HTML files without any issues.

I'm not really sure on what happens when you hit F5 on VS. I expected the the wwwroot folder and the client dlls would be copied to the output folder of the server project, but that isn't happening.Instead, it seems like the static middleware is configured to return the HTML file from the client's wwwroot project when the environment is set to `Development` (and that isn't being done when I change the environment).

I've tried passing a custom `StaticFileOptions` object to the `MappFallbackToFile` method that uses the physical client's wwwroot folder. When doing this, I do end up serving the HTML file, but then it seems unable to find the blazo js file and the autogenerated css file (with the name of the project).

So, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here? how can I configure a new environment for Blazor app that can be used from within VS 2022?

Comment: [This answer should be a workaround.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63061239/7687666) Hope it will help you.

Comment: Hi. Well, not really. The issue I'm having is that using a custom environment (which is not named production, staging or development) doesn't seem to work when using Kestrel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if you want to use a custom environment, you need to call the `UseStaticWebAssets` as mentioned on this [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/42081).